# Starting and Stopping custom Windows Service Without Admin Privileges

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, windows-services, admin

I have created a windows service and successfully added into the Windows Service List.Now i want my users to start and stop this service using button click from Windows Form Application In Visual Studio.I created the same and it is working if the application gets launched with Admin Privileges.This i dont want because my users wont have the admin privileges .So my question is can i Control i.e start and stop windows Service Without Admin Privileges.Also i have created my windows Service as Local System.

My question is How can i give normal users right to start and Stop my custom windows Service From Button Click using c#.
Please help me.Thanks in advance..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek thank you ,i will take care of this ..

Comment: Isn't this a rather large security hole that you attempting to create?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - the starting and stopping of a service by any given user *may* have security implications or it may have none. There's a reason why services are secured with ACLs - because there's not a universal, one-size-fits-all security model around them.

Comment: @Damien So you can grant a specific rights to control a specific service? I thought control was coarser.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan how to do it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - yes, see the answer in the question this one is linked to as a duplicate.